# Only screen-reading a child element when it is highlighted

Tags: html, accessibility

I have an element roughly like this:

```
<a class="parent" tabindex="0">
   <span class="info">One line of data.</span>
   <span class="info">Another line of data.</span>
   <button class="action">Click here to do stuff.</button>
</a>
```

Because of reasons, I have a link that takes users to a certain page, and inside that link is a button that does something related to the link, but functionally different. When I tab over the `parent` link with a screen reader, it reads the text of everything inside - both `info` spans and the `button`, which is not the behavior I'm looking for. What I want to happen is:

- If a user tabs to the `parent` link, it reads off the contents of the two `info` spans, but not the `button`, as this would mislead users about what the link does.
- If a user tabs specifically to the `button`, the contents of the button is read off.

I tried assembling a custom `aria-label` for the `parent` link to do what I want, but it proved to be very difficult because some of the content I want to be read is interpolated HTML, which doesn't go very easily into an English string. Is there an easier way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: have you tried putting the two spans in a div, and the button in a separate div. Your "parent" div become the grandparent div, and you can give the div with the span elements the "parent" class.

Comment: @Justin well the classes aren't really important, they're just to identify functions in this example. And the "parent" div isn't a div, it's a link. Basically, I want the link to have a different function than the button included in the link, which is why I want the contents read out separately.

Comment: Nesting one clickable element inside another is always going to give strange results as different browsers/screenreaders try to work out which one to give precedence to. The first thing you should try is using a proper href attribute on the link - screenreaders may treat it differently, and then you won't need the tabindex for keyboard focus either.